# Existence of bijective proofs involving Yamanouchi words?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics

The following notion comes from algebraic combinatorics and might have some connections to language/permutation theory. Fix an integer $k$. Let us call a *$k$-Yamanouchi word* a sequence $u$ of integers in $[k]$ such that (i) for every prefix $v$ of $u$, we have $|v|_k \geq |v|_{k-1} \geq \ldots \geq |v|_1$, (ii) when $v = u$, the equalities hold.

These words generalize the notion of Dyck words, which are basically 2-Yamanouchi words. It is well-known that Dyck words are counted by Catalan numbers and can be put in bijection with numerous objects (see e.g. [here](http://mupad-combinat.sourceforge.net/doc/en/combinat/dyckWords.html)). On the other hand, $k$-Yamanouchi words are in bijection with Young tableaux of rectangular shape $k \times n$, and thus are counted by the "hook length formula":

$Y^k_n = \frac{(kn)!}{n! (n+1)! \ldots (n+k)!}.$

I'm not aware of any other known bijections involving $k$-Yamanouchi words, so I am asking for possible references or new bijections, involving for instance trees or permutations. A note of caution: these objects seem much harder to handle algebraically than Dyck words so it's not clear whether they can give rise to "well-structured" objects such as trees.